# Auth0 and ADAL.NET

Tags: auth0, adal

I am trying to get an access token from my Auth0 setup, I am using ADAL. I don't understand why it's trying to connect to the following site when I look at fiddler:

https://login.windows.net/common/discovery/instance?api-version=1.0&authorization_endpoint=https://myusername.auth0.com/oauth/oauth2/authorize

Here is my code:

```
var AuthCtx = new AuthenticationContext("https://MYUSERNAME.auth0.com/oauth/token");
var token = AuthCtx.AcquireTokenAsync("https://api.MYSITE.COM", new ClientCredential("clientid here", "secret here"));
Console.WriteLine(token.Result.AccessToken);
```

Thank you!

Comment: The ADAL credentials need to be validated on its AAD trusted site.

Answer (score 2):

ADAL is a Microsoft library that is developed to connect native devices (non-browser) e.g. desktop & mobile to either Azure AD or ADFS.

You can use it for other Identity providers but it is not supported as a generic OAuth stack.

All the samples either use Azure AD or ADFS.

The endpoint above is the common endpoint for Azure AD.